# TV started reporting no signal from HDMI Port

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, hdmi

After 6 months of using my LG5500 as an external monitor for my Acer Aspire E1-472g laptop connected via the HDMI port, two days ago the TV started responding "No Signal". It is possible that what triggered this is while connected my laptop went into sleep mode and then my TV also went into sleep mode. I can connect using a VGA cable but because of resolution limitation this is not so good. When I look at Systems Settings...> Displays my HDMI connection to the TV appears, however the TV reports "No Signal". I have tried a different HDMI cable tested on my DVD player which works fine. Any suggestions appreciated. Info below:

```
barry@barry-Aspire-E1-472G:~$ sudo lshw -C display; lsb_release -a; uname -a; sudo dmidecode -t 1
[sudo] password for barry: 
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:63 memory:f3000000-f33fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:5000(size=64)
  *-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:66 memory:f2000000-f2ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128)
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
Linux barry-Aspire-E1-472G 3.13.0-49-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 10 20:11:33 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# dmidecode 2.12
# SMBIOS entry point at 0xcaf09000
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x000C, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
    Manufacturer: Acer
    Product Name: Aspire E1-472G
    Version: V2.11
    Serial Number: NXMK1ST00741907E186600
    UUID: 46B32C88-B5B4-EC40-A00B-C460DFEB9018
    Wake-up Type: Other
    SKU Number: Aspire E1-472G_0762_2.11
    Family: Aspire E1-472G
```